# Why do we add 2 to the denominator when doing laplace smoothing?

Tags: probability, bayesian, naive-bayes

Every explanation of laplace smoothing for, e.g, spam filtering, includes the following:

> The solution is to never let any word probabilities be zero, by smoothing them upwards. Instead of
> starting each word count at 0, start it at 1. This way none of the counts will ever have a numerator
> of 0. This overestimates the word probability, so we also add 2 to the denominator. (We add 2 because
> we’re implicitly keeping track of 2 things: the number of emails that contain that word, and the number
> that don’t. The sum of those two things should be in the denominator, and the 2 accounts for starting
> both the counters at 1.)

I don't understand why we add 2 to the denominator. For example, if we start every word count at 1, this is equivalent to adding an email to our dataset with 1 of each word.

And, since the formula for calculating $P(w_1|S)$ is $\frac{\text{# of spam emails containing }w_1}{\text{total # of spam emails}}$, shouldn't we just add 1 to the numerator and denominator?

If possible, please explain with a very simple example/dataset with concrete numbers. My guess is that the explanation should include something about the probabilities not summing to 1, if you only add 1 to the denominator (instead of 2).

Comment: This is fully explained in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing).  You can learn all about it by searching here for [Dirichlet prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182992/dirichlet-prior-for-multinomial)